# SQL error: query empty

Tags: php, sql

```
mysql_select_db("musicDB", $con);

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (username, fname, lname, email, dob, password, occupation, genre )
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[dob]', sha1('$_POST[password]'), '$_POST[occupation]', '$_POST[genre]')");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
?>
```

I am new to PHP and I am getting this SQL error:

> The query is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome SQLI... read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (username, fname, lname, email, dob, password, occupation, genre )
VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[dob]', sha1('$_POST[password]'), '$_POST[occupation]', '$_POST[genre]')");

if (!sql)
{
```

is correct one. You were trying to do

```
if(!mysql_query(mysql_query("....")))
{
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_select_db("musicDB", $con);

// that's dirty but at least something to protect that silly code
$_POST['password'] = sha1($_POST['password'].$_POST['username']);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, fname, lname, email, dob, password, occupation, genre )
        VALUES ('$_POST[username]', '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[lname]', '$_POST[email]',
                '$_POST[dob]', '$_POST[password]', '$_POST[occupation]', '$_POST[genre]')");

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
    trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
} else {
    echo "1 record added";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

when declaring the string query variable, dont use `$sql = mysql_query(...);` just simply `$sql = "...";` and it should work fine